# Linear equivalence of divisors in smooth algebraic surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let's assume $X$ is a smooth algebraic surface and $C$ a curve containing a smooth point $p_0\in X$, then there exist divisors $H_1$ and $H_2$ non of which contain $p_0$ such that $C+H_1$ is linearly equivalent to $H_2$.

Comment: This is a fairly straightforward consequence of the definition of ample divisor. It's probably useful to work out the details for yourself.

Comment: Besides, it is worded like a homework problem, not as a question.